# ActiveRecord selection, modified by optional parameters

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, active-record

I have an action method in my Rails controller which filters an ActiveRecord model depending on the submitted GET parameters.
[Rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/tree/v0.40.0) complains that [Assignment Branch Condition Size](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/v0.40.0/lib/rubocop/cop/metrics/abc_size.rb) is too high: `20.62/15`.

Is there a way to improve the following code?

```
@measurements = Measurement.all
@measurements = @measurements.where(sensor_id: params[:sensor_id].split(',')) if params[:sensor_id].present?
@measurements = @measurements.last_per_sensor(params[:last_per_sensor]) if params[:last_per_sensor].present?
@measurements = @measurements.last(params[:last]) if params[:last].present?
```

Answer (score 3):

Some notes:

- That's too much code for a controller method, it should be moved to the model.
- The same name (`@measurements`) holds up to 4 different values. As a general rule, avoid variable rebinding: different values, different names.
- More about how the filtering method could be written keeping it DRY: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4480285/188031

For example:

```
class Measurement < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.filter(attributes)
    attributes.select { |k, v| v.present? }.reduce(all) do |scope, (key, value)|
      case key.to_sym
      when :sensor_id
        scope.where(key => value)
      when :last, :last_per_sensor 
        scope.send(key, value)
      else
        scope
      end 
    end
  end
end
```

And in the controller simply:

```
@measurements = Measurement.filter(params.slice(:sensor_id, :last, :last_per_sensor))
```